# Default text color of axes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the color of the text of the x-axis in ggplot if a condition is met. No problem but for that, I have to know which is the default color of the x-axis in `theme_minimal()`. I looked in the source code, that leaded me to `theme_bw()` which lead me to `theme_grey()` which you can find here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/theme-defaults.r
I see the declaration of many colors but not the one of the `x-axis`?

Comment: can you show a minimum [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on what have you tried? Because it works for me, I'm able to change the text color of `x-axis`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2` package's `calc_element()` to figure out what you want. In this case, the default font colour for x-axis text is "grey30":

```
> calc_element("axis.text.x", theme_minimal())
List of 11
 $ family       : chr ""
 $ face         : chr "plain"
 $ colour       : chr "grey30"
 $ size         : num 8.8
 $ hjust        : num 0.5
 $ vjust        : num 1
 $ angle        : num 0
 $ lineheight   : num 0.9
 $ margin       : 'margin' num [1:4] 2.2pt 0pt 0pt 0pt
  ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 8
  ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "pt"
 $ debug        : logi FALSE
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_text" "element"
```

Comment: Thank you! Couln't imagine a better answer!